# Node uses 150% of CPU on sass compile

Tags: node.js, sass, cpu-usage, watch

I found lots of issues with offered solutions on node using cpu but no one solved my problem - mostly it was said to install fsevents and rebuild, remove node modules and reinstall. Also was offered to add poll:false, but I'm not sure I have web-pack. I'm practicing sass so it's a very simple app having only sass installed as a node module, and the script is:

```
"scripts": {
        "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"
}
```

So all I use is live-server and npm run compile:sass.

**Versions**:
node-sass: "^4.14.1",
Node: "^14.15.0"

I tried to see what's going on with node cpu consumption when running other apps that do not include that script, and the consumption was adequate.

Besides all of that I tried to change versions of node-sass (to 4.13.1) and nodejs (to 14.15.4) and also I deleted the node-sass globally.

Does anyone know what can be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in live-server - not in nodejs or node-sass as I thought.

If I understand right, live-server watched node_modules folder which had node-sass watching as well, and that caused such CPU load.

Once node_modules will be ignored by live-server, the problem is solved.